# Double Quotes inside Double Quotes problem for postgres sensitive database name priviliges

Tags: command-line, bash, postgresql

Having a database with case sensitive name like MyDb,

if I want to use psql to grant all privileges on this database to the user 'user' I can just write:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE "MyDb" TO user;
```

it works.

But what if I want to use shell scripts?

Running the following command:

```
su - postgres -c "psql -c \"GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE \"MyDb\" TO user;\""
```

fails with the error like: `ERROR:  database "mydb" does not exist`

Comment: No,
its not working!

Comment: Why use `su` at all? Why not `sudo -u postgres psql -c 'GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE "MyDb" TO user;'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use singlequotes :

```
postgres=# \l
                                 List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |  Collate   |   Ctype    |   Access privileges   
-----------+----------+----------+------------+------------+-----------------------
 MyDb      | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | 

$ su - postgres -c 'psql -c "grant all privileges on database \"MyDb\" to user;"'  
GRANT
```

But be careful, as if you're using variables inside the singlequotes, they will not be expanded. In your specific case, it's ok though.

**Edit**: you also need to escape the doublequotes inside the request, so they are correctly passed to PostGres, in order to indicate that the DB name is case-sensitive.

Comment: It doesn't work! I said the datebase name was case senstive MyDb!

Comment: I edited the answer to take into account the fact that the DB name is case sensitive.